# left to right radix sort

Tags: algorithm, string, sorting, radix-sort

Radix sort sorts the numbers starting from lease significant digit to most significant digit. 
I have the following scenario :

My alphabet is the english alphabet and therefore my "numbers" are english language strings. The characters of these strings are revealed one at a time left to right. That is, the most significant digit , for all strings, is revealed first and so on. At any stage, i will have a set of k character long strings, that is sorted. At this point one character more is revealed for every string. And i want to sort the new set of strings. How do i do this efficiently without starting from scratch ?

For example if i had the following sorted set { for, for, sta, sto, sto }

And after one more character each is revealed, the set is { form, fore, star, stop, stoc }

The new sorted set should be {fore, form, star, stoc, stop }

I m hoping for a complexity O(n) after each new character is added,  where n is the size of the set.

Comment: This sounds fully equivalent to MSD radix sort (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Most_significant_digit_radix_sorts).

Comment: @Alexey It is different in the sense that more digits can be revealed later, so it is sort of an online algorithm, whereas for MSD radix sort, the complete numbers should be available beforehand

Comment: Right. It's as if you always had one more digit to sort, so "fully equivalent" is not totally correct I agree.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in O(n) you have to somehow keep track of "groups":

```
for, for | sta | sto, sto
```

Within this groups, you can sort the strings according to their last character keeping the set sorted.

Storing groups can be done in various ways. At first sight, I would recommend some kind of remembering offsets of group beginnings/endings. However, this consumes extra memory.

Another possibility might be storing the strings in some kind of [prefix-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), which correspond quite naturally to "adding one char after another", but I don't know if this is suitable for your application.

Comment: I had been toying with the groups idea, but i cant seem to do better than min ( O(bn) , O(nlgn)) where b is the size of the alphabet. I doubt if there is a natural solution using prefix tree that allows dynamic construction and visiting leaves in sorted order in linear time

Comment: @AnkurVj You could try to add a linked list "below" the prefix tree so you can use the prefix tree for navigating through the elements and use the list for retrieving all elements. On the other hand, including this linked list implies more work to be done when inserting/removing elements from the prefix tree.